# Make folders nodes in TreeView, and move nodes between them

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I want to make a treeview structure like [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/reorder.html). I can only find an example on how to copy nodes.

But I don't know how to organize it to folders, to move nodes between them. Any advice will be very helpful.
I'm using `winforms`.

Comment: I find this http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1308, it's working, now I tring to make inserting node between nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are going to have a recursive loop like so:

```
protected void Populate(TreeNode parentNode, DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directory.GetDirectories())
    {
        TreeNode node = parentNode.Nodes[dir.Name] 
            ?? parentNode.Nodes.Add(dir.Name, dir.Name);
        node.Tag = dir;
        // node.ContextMenuStrip = cmenu;
        Populate(node, dir);
    }
}
```

To drag and drop with TreeView, see this [Microsoft example.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307968)